# Chain falls off my wife's E bike

Tags: chain, chain-guide

Is there a chain keeper or chain guide available for a single sprocket E bike type frame bike to stop chain from coming of the front single sprocket?

Comment: There are many types of chain keepers and guides. Can you show a photo of your bike?

Comment: Except for fairly techical Mountain biking, chain keepers should not be needed and it would be better to find the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If your chain is coming off of the single front sprocket, you probably need to tighten the chain or get a new chain.

Use a chain checker to see if your chain is stretched out and needs to be replaced. If not, some bike frames have a longer space instead of just a single hole where the back wheel can move a bit. Just loosen the back wheel and see if it can move back a bit and tighten it in place. But I'd doubt an e-bike would have that kind of variability.

If none of that works, you may need to ask the bike shop to look it over. There may be [many other reasons](https://mountaintreads.com/reasons-why-mountain-bike-chains-come-off/) this is happening.